# Is it possible to make the code of components you add to java smaller?

Tags: java, swing, components

I was wondering if we are adding the same components to java (in the main class)over and over again and writing separate code for each of them, would it be possible to make the code smaller? e.g. if we are adding buttons and labels many times, which each do different job, would it it possible to have them in less code or does it have to be like that e.g.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Text1");
label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
panel.add(label);
JTextField field = new JTextField();
panel.add(field);

JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Text2");
label1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
panel.add(label1);
JTextField field1 = new JTextField();
panel.add(field1);

JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Text3");
label2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
panel.add(label2);
JTextField field2 = new JTextField();
panel.add(field2);
```

In my code I have to add the same components over and over again like 10 times but each one is doing a different job, would it be possible to have them in less code?

edit:

```
 String[] labelNames = {"label1", "label2", "label3",};
 String[] fieldNames = {"Name1", "Name2", "Name3",};
 String[] labelTexts = {"Text1", "Text2", "Text3"};
 Map<String, JTextField> fieldMap = new HashMap<>();
 // for loop here to add JLabels
 for (String text : labelTexts) {
    for (int i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < labelNames.length; j++) {
   JLabel labelNames = new JLabel(text);
   panel.add(labelNames);
   JTextField fieldName = new JTextField(10);
   panel.add(fieldName);
   fieldMap.put(text, fieldName);
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry the code is messed up, just editing it right now

Comment: hi @Krazick, What are subroutines?

Comment: This will end in 3x3x3 Labels etc. Aren't you just going for 3 of each?

Answer (score 3):

Use collections or arrays, and loops to simplify things:

```
String[] labelTexts = {"Text1", "Text2", "Text3"};
Map<String, JTextField> fieldMap = new HashMap<>();
// for loop here to add JLabels
for (String text : labelTexts) {
  JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
  panel.add(label);
  JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
  panel.add(field);
  fieldMap.put(text, field);
}
```

For example, I used the above type of code in this example:

```
class PlayerEditorPanel extends JPanel {
   enum FieldTitle {
      NAME("Name"), SPEED("Speed"), STRENGTH("Strength");
      private String title;

      private FieldTitle(String title) {
         this.title = title;
      }

      public String getTitle() {
         return title;
      }
   };

   private static final Insets WEST_INSETS = new Insets(5, 0, 5, 5);
   private static final Insets EAST_INSETS = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 0);
   private static final double SCALE = 0.4;
   private Map<FieldTitle, JTextField> fieldMap = new HashMap<FieldTitle, JTextField>();
   private BufferedImage backgroundImg = null;
   private int imgWidth;
   private int imgHeight;

   public PlayerEditorPanel(BufferedImage img) {
      this.backgroundImg = img;
      imgWidth = (int) (backgroundImg.getWidth() * SCALE);
      imgHeight = (int) (backgroundImg.getHeight() * SCALE);

      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
            BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Player Editor"),
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)));
      GridBagConstraints gbc;
      for (int i = 0; i < FieldTitle.values().length; i++) {
         FieldTitle fieldTitle = FieldTitle.values()[i];
         gbc = createGbc(0, i);
         JLabel fieldLabel = new JLabel(fieldTitle.getTitle() + ":",
               JLabel.LEFT);
         fieldLabel.setForeground(new Color(200, 10, 10));
         fieldLabel.setFont(fieldLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 24f));
         add(fieldLabel, gbc);
         gbc = createGbc(1, i);
         JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
         add(textField, gbc);

         fieldMap.put(fieldTitle, textField);
      }
   }

   @Override
   @Transient
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (backgroundImg != null) {
         return new Dimension(imgWidth, imgHeight);
      }

      return super.getPreferredSize();
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      if (backgroundImg != null) {
         g.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight, this);
      }
   }

   private GridBagConstraints createGbc(int x, int y) {
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = x;
      gbc.gridy = y;
      gbc.gridwidth = 1;
      gbc.gridheight = 1;

      gbc.anchor = (x == 0) ? GridBagConstraints.WEST : GridBagConstraints.EAST;
      gbc.fill = (x == 0) ? GridBagConstraints.BOTH
            : GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

      gbc.insets = (x == 0) ? WEST_INSETS : EAST_INSETS;
      gbc.weightx = (x == 0) ? 0.1 : 1.0;
      gbc.weighty = 1.0;
      return gbc;
   }

   public String getFieldText(FieldTitle fieldTitle) {
      return fieldMap.get(fieldTitle).getText();
   }

}
```

in this answer here: [How to align multiple textfields on a background image within a JOptionPane?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17872134/522444)

---

**Edit**

You state in comment:

> I have used a JFrame.

- First and foremost, you should avoid having your Swing GUI classes extend JFrame as that unnecessarily paints your GUI code into a corner that requires a bit of effort to get out of.
- Instead gear your Swing GUI code towards making JPanels, panels which now can easily be placed into other JPanels, or into JFrames, JDialogs, JOptionPanes, swapped in CardLayouts,... wherever they are needed.
- Instead, create, fill, and pack your JFrames when they are needed.

---

**Edit 2**
You ask:

> So the name of each label and field we are adding through for loop will be named as label1, label2 etc. and field1, field2 etc. Is it possible to change the name of each field/label to something different e.g. instead of field 1, 2, 3 have number, string and double etc and for label, instead of label 1, 2 and 3 have numanswer, stringanswer, doubanswer etc.

Sure, you can use whatever name you desire. There's no magic associated with the numeric labels.

> how can I get the text of individual textfield and set it to different variables? e.g. first textfield to a variable firstnumber, second textfield to userinput and so on.

I never got to what is really the crux of my code -- I use a Map to associate the JTextField with another object, such as a String or enum, and by doing this, allow easy extraction of the text held by the JTextField using the String or enum as a key.

For instance in my latter example, I use an enum of three items (the number of items can be anything) called FieldTitle, and use that enum to create both my JLabel text and as a *key* to the map for each associated JTextField. I use a for loop to loop through an array of the enum items (held by the enum `values()` method), and in that loop, I create my JLabel and JTextField, add them into my JPanel using GridBagLayout so that the data appears as a table with each label text field pair comprising a row of the table. I then add the newly created JTextField to the Map using the enum as the key: `fieldMap.put(fieldTitle, textField);`. Then when any outside class wants to extract the text held by a JTextField, they only have to call the `getFieldText` method, pass in the appropriate enum, and get their String.

Comment: I am working on it atm, trying different things, I will let you know my results.

Comment: Hovercraft, I deleted some of my comments to prevent this from flooding this chat. Also, I had several goes and I came to this but it is not properly. (edited my code).

Comment: Hovercraft can you please show me how its done, I had several attempts but none are working properly.